# hover and/or click, autofocus input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an icon that when I hover it sets focus to the input field. However I want to also add the functionality if the user clicks on the same icon, the input field will get focus.

```
    if(!mobile){
    $('#search-icon').hover( 
        function(){
            if($('.search-area').css('display') == 'none'){
                $('#search-dd').css('display', 'block');
                $('.search-area').css('display', 'block');
                $('.search-input').focus();
            }
        }, function(){
            if($('.search-area').css('display') != 'none') {
            $('#search-dd').css('display', 'none');
            $('.search-area').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    $('#search-icon').on('click', function(){

        if($('.search-area').css('display') == 'none'){
            $('#search-dd').css('display', 'block');
            $('.search-area').css('display', 'block');
            $('#search-input').focus();
        }
        else if($('.search-area').css('display') != 'none') {
            $('#search-dd').css('display', 'none');
            $('.search-area').css('display', 'none');
            $('#search-input').focus();
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to click, I get no focus. What am I missing?

Comment: how about using wrapping your icon inside label for click to focus functionalty?

Comment: In the code above you have a class of "search-input" while you are using it as id inside on(click). Change it to $(".search-input").focus();

Comment: I just realized my error....thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just if someone looking for a solution, actually its a typo here :

"In the code above you have a class of "search-input" while you are using it as id inside on(click). Change it to $(".search-input").focus();"

Answer (score 0):

You can attach attach your event(s) to `#search-icon` but not need for a `click` event when you can use the html feature:

```js
$('#search-icon').on('hover, mouseover', function() {
    $('#search').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="search" id="search-icon">Icon area: </label>
<input id="search" type="text" />
```

Comment: he need `hover`, not only `mouseover`